# MySQL Range partitioning vs Hash partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning

We have one large table with 100 million records and its size is 100 GB and data is continuously growing day by day. This table has 30 partitions with `RANGE by client_id(table's column)`. One `client_id` is having minimum 1 million records.

For solution we have break this large table into 30 small tables with group of `client_id` data in each table. Now we want to do partition in each table.

- So which partition would work for us best: **Range** or **Hash**?

We don't know which table has which set of `client_id`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Neither.

**Long answer**:

Partitioning is not a panacea.  It does not automatically provide performance.  In fact, it sometimes slows down processing.

I have never see a use case where `BY HASH` helped.  I have seen a *few* use cases for `BY RANGE`.  Off hand, it does not sound like your use case will benefit.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a few of the critical `SELECTs`.  With those, I will either

- Explain why partitioning is useless.  Or...
- Explain how to benefit from partitioning for *those* queries.

In either case, I will probably suggest index (including PK) changes.  *Proper indexes is where performance usually comes from.*

In another direction...  Is this some form of "multi-tenant" app?  Will it eventually out-grow the server?  If so, **Sharding** may be in your future.  This is when you scatter "clients" (or whatever) across multiple servers.  But, alas, MySQL does not have any built-in support of such.  There are 3rd party packages (eg, Spider) that do.

Comment: Adding to @Rick's answer - if some clients have a lot more data than others, AND those clients get queried frequently, then partitioning on client_id could result in a few partitions being very busy while others are relatively idle. This would result in a very uneven distribution of the workload, quite possibly with no improvement or even worse performance than before.